# getting rid of Http on a <a> tag

Tags: php, html

I have code that puts a web address into a variable to be used in a `<a>` tag. The issue is when people input `http://ect` with their address then the `<a>` tag adds another `http://` on to it, then the link wont work. Is there a way to remove `http://` from the `<a>` tag.

example

```
<a href="http://<?php echo ($data->website); ?>" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

If `$data = "www.example.com"` it'll work.
But `$data = "http://www.example.com"` it wont.

Thank you in advance. I know I'm a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following,

$url = remove_http($data->website);

Add following Funciton in your file.

```
function remove_http($url) {
   $disallowed = array('http://', 'https://');
   foreach($disallowed as $d) {
      if(strpos($url, $d) === 0) {
         return str_replace($d, '', $url);
      }
   }
   return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! Though many of the answers would of worked I liked your function best. Was not disappointed for my first question!

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `http://` with emptyString

Try like this

```
$data->website=str_replace("http://","",$data->website);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove it, since a lot of URL:s begin with http**s**. Instead, you should only *add* it if it's missing.
Check if the user's input contains "://", and if it doesn't, add "http://" in the beginning of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Since restricting users is not a good idea, By a very simple code you can accept both http:// included and not included.

```
$newaddress = str_ireplace("http://","", $address);
```

this code will remove http:// from the address if it has.